# Maximum call stack size exceeded, on click dispatch

Tags: javascript, onclick, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux toolkit to add a object to my array , for that i'm dispatching a function but i'm getting this error (i'm importing data into my details file by help of state and params):

*" Details.js:16 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at addToCart (Details.js:16:1) "*

here is my details file

```
import {react,useEffect} from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {getProduct,addtocart} from '../features/productSlice'


function Details(){
    const params = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(getProduct(params.id))
    },[])

    function addToCart(){
        dispatch(addToCart(id));
    }

    const productdetail = useSelector((state)=> state.myproduct.product)
    const {title,image,description,price,id}= productdetail;

   console.log(params)
    return(
        <>
        <div className='container'>
             <img src={image}/>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <h5>{description}</h5>
            <h4>{price}</h4> 
        </div>
        <button 
            className='btn btn-warning'
            onClick={()=>{addToCart({id}) } 
        }
            > Add to cart </button>
         </>
    )
}

export default Details;
```

*and here is my portion of Slice*

```
    const productSlice = createSlice({
        name:"myproduct",
        initialState,
        reducers:{
            getProduct:(state,action)=>{
                state.product = state.products.find((el) => el.id == action.payload)
            },
            addtocart:(state,action)=>{
                state.cart = state.cart.push(action.payload)
            },
            removefromcart:(state,action)=>{
                state.cart = action.payload
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
function addToCart({ id } = {}) {
    // dispatch(addToCart(id)); <- wrong, calls itself untill exceeds max call stack size throwing a RangeError
    dispatch(addtocart({ payload: id })); // i expect this to work, because "addtocart" is the action you're importing from "productSlice"
}
```

sidenotes:

- i would pass simply `id` instead of `{ id }` to "addToCart" button handler, and wrap the `id` in `{ payload: { id } }`
- i would rename "addtocart" to "addToCart" and import it as "addToCartAction" (same goes to all other actions from `productSlice`)

Comment: getting same error for another function   `function removeFromCart(id){
        dispatch(removeFromCart({ payload: id }));
    }`

Comment: Karan, you're getting the same error for another function because you're repeating the same mistake in this function


you're calling `removeFromCart` inside `removeFromCart` which would call `removeFromCart` and then again and again and again.. untill the call stack exceeds maximum

.The very same would happen for any other function you would call inside itself without an exit condition. google search "recursion" to learn more

Comment: Thank you , firstly i ignored your advice to _import actions_ as `xyzAction` but now I understand it , thanks .